# Kagami/go-face on Golang Environment error

Tags: go, dlib

I am having this problem which has drive me crazy for a few days. I tried to install Kagami/go-face lib in Golang for my project. I already installed dlib library using MSYS successfully. I also download Kagami/go-face from git into GOPATH directory. However, when I run 'go run main.go' command in my Golang project, it show this message error:

```
PS C:\Users\DELL\go\src\go-face-example> go run main.go
# github.com/Kagami/go-face
classify.cc:2:10: fatal error: dlib/graph_utils.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <dlib/graph_utils.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: "I already installed dlib library" --- with headers?

Comment: yes, with a lot of header files. I am suspecting maybe something is wrong with mkheaders of the gcc of the mingw64, but I am still trying to figure it out.